# Pass Json Value to UICollection View

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uicollectionview

i want to display my images in grid view. i have used UICollection view controller,data which is i'm passing in JSON format.i cant able to display images using JSON format. Can anyone pls find my mistake? Here is my code

```
@interface ReceipeCollectionViewController()
{
    NSMutableData *webdata;
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableArray *contentarray;
    NSMutableArray *array;
}

@end

@implementation ReceipeCollectionViewController

(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [array removeAllObjects];
    [[self collectionView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self collectionView]setDataSource:self];
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     
}

(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *serverurl=@"http://wesotech.com/web/myrecipe/web_services/recipe_listing.php?";
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:serverurl];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection)
    {
        webdata=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection failure");
    }
}

(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webdata appendData:data];
}

(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Fail with error");
}

(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:&error];
    [array removeAllObjects];
    [array addObjectsFromArray:results];
    [[self collectionView]reloadData];
}

(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webdata setLength:0];
}

(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}

(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.mySpinner stopAnimating];

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];

     recipeImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]]]];

    UITextField *recipeTitleView =(UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];

    recipeTitleView.text=[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"recname"];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

My JSON Format is,

```
[

    {"image":"http:\/\/wesotech.com\/web\/myrecipe\/recipeimages\/2016080614704658059030.jpg","recname":"Italian Chicken","recid":"1"},
    {"image":"http:\/\/wesotech.com\/web\/myrecipe\/recipeimages\/2016080614704653421637.jpg","recname":"Fast Food Friday","recid":"2"},
    {"image":"http:\/\/wesotech.com\/web\/myrecipe\/recipeimages\/2016080614704648912893.jpg","recname":"Honey Clazed Lamb Chops","recid":"3"}

]
```

Comment: Have you added traces or breakpoints to check if you get the correct URL, if the image is correctly loaded...? Also, your code doesn't quite show where/how the `UIImageView` comes from. Have you also checked constraints on it? It may have the correct image but just have a 0 size or something similar. Using the view debugger would provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of escaping your URL with `\`, use percentage encoding in your JSON and decode it back to unescaped string using the below code

```
NSString *imageUrl = @"http%3A%2F%2Fwesotech.com%2Fweb%2Fmyrecipe%2Frecipeimages%2F2016080614704658059030.jpg";
NSString *url = [imageUrl stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
```

> **Another important point:** Since you are loading an image with `http://`, you should set `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES` under `App Transport Security Settings` in your `info.plist` file.
>
> *Also, make a note that it is not advisable to set allow arbitrary loads as it would result in security issues. It would be better if you
>   could have all your network calls to use `https://`*

Comment: Just know that [Apple will require HTTPS connections for iOS apps by the end of 2016](https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/)

Answer (score 0):

Make a class of tableViewCell and assign that class name to cell of collectionView in utility area. Make the outlet of imageView in tableViewCell Class and access it in cellForItemAtIndexPath delegate method.
Then assign the image with this code :

```
[cell. recipeImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]]];
```

This will surely help you.